# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: jqmData

Tags: jquery-mobile

Trying to do a simple selection like so:

`$('div:jqmData(role=collapsible)')`

But I get the follwing error (from Chrome console):

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: jqmData`

My understanding from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html is that one should use the `:jqmData` selector, but it doesn't seem to work. Or I'm doing it wrong. Either way... ideas?

Comment: Can you specify the jquerymobile & jquery version? most probably you are using the latest jquery which is not compatible with jquerymobile

Comment: jQuery 1.7.1, jQuery Mobile 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you look at the syntax you linked to your missing a pair of quotes around the actual *role*

Try

```
 $("div:jqmData(role='collapsible')")
```